# Plotting times that are too close together

Tags: python, matplotlib

My plot has the datetimes bunched together too closely.

I have the following code:

```
import pandas as pd
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import matplotlib.dates as md
import matplotlib.dates as mdates


data = {"Date":['2019-2-25 14:24:04', '2019-2-25 14:29:02', '2019-2-20 17:02:14',
                '2019-3-25 08:12:54', '2019-3-25 12:32:32'],
        "Quiz":[1,2,2,3,4],
        "Score":[10,3,7,4,9]}

df = pd.DataFrame.from_dict(data)

df.Date = pd.to_datetime(df.Date)   

fig = plt.figure(figsize = (11,9))
ax = fig.add_subplot(111)

ax.set_xticks(df.Date)
ax.xaxis.set_major_formatter(mdates.DateFormatter('%d/%m/%Y %H:%M'))
ax.set_xlabel("Date")
ax.set_ylabel("Score")

ax.plot_date(df.Date, df.Score)

fig.autofmt_xdate(rotation=45)
plt.show()
```

And here is the plot:

[image]

I would like to plot the dates of my data. However, some datetimes are too close together and I haven't been able to figure out a way to space them evenly apart. How can I accomplish this?

Comment: I guess it would make more sense to have your xticklabels as a linear progression, let's says from 20th of Feb to 25th of March, with a label written every seven days maybe. Then, if you want more accuracy for your dots, you can probably annotate them on the graph.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:

```
import pandas as pd
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import matplotlib.dates as md
import matplotlib.dates as mdates
import datetime as dt

data = {"Date":['2019-2-25 14:24:04', '2019-2-25 14:29:02', '2019-2-20 17:02:14',
                '2019-3-25 08:12:54', '2019-3-25 12:32:32'],
        "Quiz":[1,2,2,3,4],
        "Score":[10,3,7,4,9]}

df = pd.DataFrame.from_dict(data)

xs = df.Date.values

fig, ax = plt.subplots(1)

ax.set_xlabel("Date")
ax.set_ylabel("Score")

ax.plot_date(xs, df.Score)

fig.autofmt_xdate(rotation=45)
plt.show()
```

The main difference is removing the formatting business and setting xs = `df.Date.values`, then letting the chart take care of the formatting on its own with `fig.autofmt_xdate(rotation=45)`.

[image]